# How to take backup of images in container registry

Tags: docker, backup, azure-webjobs, azure-container-registry, azure-function-app

I need to take back up of images which are store in azure container registry. The container registry is growing large with version of images. And i am planning to automate clean up process to archive images which are older or unused images.

we can do save images using docker save command in the cli

```
docker save -o <path for generated tar file> <image name>
```

But i need to automate this process for set of images which are stored in azure container registry or any registry.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to take a backup of your images to another ACR, then you can use import command - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-import-images
This even works if you want to copy images from any other registry to ACR.